# install package in subfolder

Tags: packages, installing

At the moment I have some modified and some of my own packages placed in the same folder as my tex file. I would like to move all of them in a subfolder called packages so that I have a better overview over my files. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you can always reference packages in a different directory by `\usepackage{/path/to/package/x.sty}`. Alternatively you can add them to your local texmf tree and use them that way.

Comment: that is something I already tried and didn't seem to work correctly, since it gives me the warning `You have requested package 'package/name' but the package provides 'name'`

Comment: @maetra: That is just a warning, the package is indeed loaded. (But see the other answers, which are "more proper" [with no offense to wh1t3 intended].)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all my larger LaTeX projects, I maintain a project-local `texmf` subfolder for exactly this purpose: own and modified packages, new versions of packages that are not yet part of major TeX distributions, and so on. I include this folder by setting `TEXINPUTS` in the project's `Makefile` or manually in bash: `export TEXINPUTS=./texmf//:${TEXINPUTS}`.

(Note: The double slash `//` makes LaTeX to search subfolders as well. If the project-local `texmf` folder contains also bibliography-related packages, such as a new version of `biblatex`, one also has to set `BSTINPUTS` accordingly.)

One often hears that additional/own packages or updates to existing packages better go into the machine-wide or user-wide `texmf` tree. This might work well if you work alone on a project on a single machine only, but it certainly does not work so well in a collaborative setting.

By maintaining all "non-standard" packages in a project-related `texmf` subfolder, I can put everything together into a version control system (such as git or subversion). Collaborating colleagues (even those that are still stuck to TexLive 2010) can check-out and built the project without having to manually install or update a dozen of LaTeX packages.

Comment: that was pretty much idea too, since I am already using subversion in a collaborative setting. But I am using windows and miktex-portable, so I have to adapt your solution. I tried to do `set UserRoots=\packages` and `set texmf=\packages` but had not success with that.

Comment: That seems like overkill, really.

Comment: @einpoklum: _That seems like overkill, really._ – yes, it does. Until the day you have to rework a ten years old project, work on the same project on three or more different computers using different environments, work with 10+ people on the same project, or just have to pass the thing in a "way that works" to your colleague or boss.

Comment: Fair enough :-(

Answer (score 8):

befor you run `pdflatex` do a `export TEXMFHOME=packages/`

Answer (score 1):

For MikTeX-Portable there doesn't exist such a simple solution as described by Daniel and Herbert, but adding the packages' path via MikTEX->Options->Add Root seems okay. One just has to take care to remove the additional path before compiling other projects that don't use the the modified but the original packages.