# MikTeX does not use TEXMFLOCAL environment variable

Tags: miktex, environment-variables

I use TEXMFLOCAL, TEXINPUTS and TEXFONTMAPS to tune tex compilation. Everything works fine under Linux and Mac OS X, but MitTeX under Windows breaks my expectations.

```
c:\tmp\tex> type test.bat
set TEXMFLOCAL=some;thing
kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL

c:\tmp\tex> test.bat

c:\tmp\tex>set TEXMFLOCAL=some;thing

c:\tmp\tex>kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL
C:/Documents and Settings/user/Application Data/MiKTeX/2.9
```

Why the value of the environment variable TEXMFLOCAL is ignored? Do I set it wrong, or is it a feature of MikTeX? How to affect MikTeX's TEXMFLOCAL, TEXINPUTS and TEXFONTMAPS from a script (.bat or .py)?

Comment: AFAIK `MikTeX` does not support `TEXMFLOCAL`, only TeX Live based distributions does. `MikTeX` has the concept of `roots` instead.

Comment: You can register a root in a script with `initexmf --register-root=path\to\root`. You can unregister it with `-unregister-root`.

Comment: The idea is _not_ to touch an existing TeX installation at all. Adding root is invasive. And after adding root, I then need to teach MikTeX about my font map file.

Comment: If the texmf tree you are trying to add contains relevant font map files (or e.g. a updmap.cfg) you will in any case have to run updmap - regardless how you announce the tree to a tex system. Adding and removing roots in miktex is easy (and is imho one of the great features of miktex which I'm using constantly) and it is the way to do it in this tex system. Use TeXLive if you don't like it.

Answer (score 6):

The only environment variables recognised (at least the documented ones) by MiKTeX globally are (MiKTeX manual, Chapter 8):

> BIBINPUTS
>   Extra paths to locate .bib files.
>
> BSTINPUTS
>   Extra paths to locate .bst files.
>
> MFINPUTS
>   Extra paths to locate METAFONT input and openin files.
>
> MIKTEX_REPOSITORY
>   Location of the package repository. This can be either a fully qualified path name (a local package repository) or an URL (a remote package repository).
>
> MIKTEX_TRACE
>   Comma-separated list of trace stream names (see Chapter 9, Trace Streams). If this variable is set, then MiKTeX programs will write trace messages into the DebugView window.
>
> MPINPUTS
>   Extra paths to locate MetaPost input files.
>
> TEXINPUTS
>   Extra paths to locate TeX \input and \openin files.
>
> TFMFONTS
>   Extra paths to locate TeX font metric files

If you want to know hot to set a local texmf tree have a look at [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/27635)

Comment: I wouldn't dare to claim that these are the only variables ;-). Not everything in miktex is documentated and some variable are only mentioned in some messages. E.g. some time ago you needed to set `MIKTEX_GS_LIB` to be able to use mgs on the command line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you please let us now which ones are not documented?

Comment: I can't. Over the years Christian mentioned some (like the MIKTEX_GS_LIB) in postings.  I don't know if they still in use or if other have been added. The documentation of miktex is not very elaborate. A lot of things which actually work fine (like e.g. --shell-escape, or `MIKTEX_EDITOR`) are not mentioned.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I hoped you knew more about them... Anyway I was aware of `MIKTEX_EDITOR` which is the equivalent of `TEXEDIT` and `MFEDIT` (BTW, I don't know why `MPEDIT` isn't substituted by that variable as well)

Comment: Just for clarification: Is the sematics regarding `TEXINPUTS`, `BSTINPUTS` and `BIBINPUTS` *different* from TexLive? For instance, does a `\usepackage` look into folders given by `TEXINPUTS`?

Comment: A bit of background: For many projects, I [maintain a project-local texmf folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31950/3751) for nonstandard or newer packages. On Linux and MacOS these are found by adding `.//:` in front of `TEXINPUTS`. Does this work with MikTex as well?

Comment: @Daniel AFAIK, this doesn't work fine in MiKTeX. You have to add `--include-directory=<localdir>` to the command-line if you want MiKTeX to search that directory before the main texmf directory.