# Installing MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 8

Tags: installing, miktex

I'm about to have my students use LaTeX. I'm a Mac user, so a simple install of MacTeX is very straightforward.

I'm concerned about students installing MiKTeX on Windows 8 as the system requirements on miktex.org say:

> MiKTeX 2.9 requires one of the following Windows operating systems:
>
> Windows 7
>
> Windows Vista with Service Pack 2 (all editions except Starter Edition)
>
> Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (all editions except Starter Edition)

So, OK to install on Windows 8? Any Windows 8 users out there using MiKTeX 2.9 successfully? If so, any installation suggestions I can share with my students?

Comment: miktex installs on windows 8 with no problems. Just match the 32 bit or 64 bit thing.

Comment: Yes it works fine on windows 8, there are plenty of videos on youtube that go through the installation process, just do a quick google search.

Comment: I’m a (usually) happy user of MiKTeX myself (Win7), but you should know, that there is a Windows version of TeX Live as well, what should much more similar to your MacTeX installation. It could otherwise happen, that something works on your machine, but not on machines with MiKTeX install, since this must be installed separately (on the other hand some things are present in MiKTeX, but not in TeX Live).)

Comment: What technique do the students use to determine if they need 32 or 64?

Comment: You can use 32-bit MiKTeX also on 64-bit machines. That’s in fact much better, because some binaries are not available for 64-bit (notably `biber` AFAIK).

Comment: Note that you could alternatively have your students install TeX Live on Windows: MacTeX is TeX Live + some Mac 'extras'. For the LaTeX course I run, we favour TeX Live simply because it means everyone has the same set up (essentially), at the cost of needing more disk space 'up front'.

Answer (score 6):

As a number of users report, there are no problems with installing MiKTeX 2.9 in Windows 8.

Let me by the way point to some notorious caveats not related to Windows 8:

- Upon installation one has to choose, if the installation should be done in administrative mode or not, see therefore [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex) (This is has nothing to do with the user “Administrator”! Also as this user you can install in user mode.)
- There’s a different philosophy with local texmf trees (TeX directory structure) compared with TeX Live/MacTeX, see [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex). Also it does not make use of these variables like `TEXMFLOCAL` or `TEXMFHOME`, see e.g. [MikTeX does not use TEXMFLOCAL environment variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118793/miktex-does-not-use-texmflocal-environment-variable).

Comment: +1, I'm running MiKTeX fine on Win 8. The only issue I faced was that the start menu entry for updating it is called `Update (Admin)` instead of `MiKTeX Update` (as suggested by the [official article](http://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex) on that subject). I've just posted to the mailing list about this issue.

Comment: @ComFreek: Thx for your reply. BTW also on Win 7 the menu entry is by default `Update` or `Update (Admin)` _without_ the distinctive “MiKTeX”. I’ve added this manually on my own machine.